# Where do I write '{' or i++; or else to make the following result?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i<=10) {while(j<10){System.out.println("Seat" + "" + i + j); j++;} i++;}
```

I want the result : "Seat 01, Seat 02, …, Seat 99" but I find only "Seat 01, Seat 02, …, Seat 09"
How do I modify the code using 'while'?

Comment: using line breaks would greatly improve the readability

Comment: What about Seat 00? Do you want it to be printed or the first one must be Seat 01?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String []args){
        for(int i = 0;i<100;i++){
            System.out.println("Seat"+String.format("%02d", i));
        }
     }
```

Comment: Use `System.out.format`, and a for loop. And declare `i`.

Answer (score 1):

you can write that :

```java
for(int i=0;i<99;i++){
   if(i<10){
      System.out.println("SEAT 0"+i);
   }else{
      System.out.println("SEAT "+i);
   }
}
```

When you know the number of loop use for. When you don't know use while. If you know that you execute your loop at least a time, use do while.

Comment: `for`and `while` loops usage is not at all related to the fact of knowing or not the number of loop to execute

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
  int j = 0;
  while (j < 10) {
    System.out.println("Seat " + i + j);
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: I mean it works but I think you should at least remove your useless "" addition in the sysout :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < 10) {

        int j = 0;

        while ( j < 10) {

            System.out.print( "Seat " + i + j + "\t" ); 

            j++;

        }

        System.out.println();

        i++;

    }
```

Live Demo [repl.it](https://repl.it/@antelove19/Where-do-I-write-or-i-or-else-to-make)